# Linq Expression Slow - Optimization needed if possible

Tags: c#, performance, linq, time-complexity

I have a list of integers "numberRangeList" containing 31 integers from 62 to 92 in sequential order, I am extracting a second list of integers "extractedList" which will contain 10 integers whose sum is equal to "total". The problem is it take about 30 seconds to compute, is there any way of speeding this up??

```
        var numberRangeList = new List<int>() { 62, 63, ...92 };
        var total = 772;
        var extractedList= (from n1 in numberRangeList
                      from n2 in numberRangeList
                      from n3 in numberRangeList
                      from n4 in numberRangeList
                      from n5 in numberRangeList
                      from n6 in numberRangeList
                      from n7 in numberRangeList
                      from n8 in numberRangeList
                      from n9 in numberRangeList
                      from n10 in numberRangeList
                      where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10 == total
                      select new List<int> { n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10 }).Take(1).First();
```

Comment: This should take forever to compute. Surprising that it even returns before the sun explodes. This does about 2^50 operations after all.

Comment: @usr: The computation shown stops when it finds the first match, due to the `.Take(1)`. And just that by itself takes the OP's machine 30 seconds.

Comment: Your problem is a very easy special case of the knapsack problem because all numbers are in the contiguous range [62, 92]. You can easily construct a match for all numbers in [62*10, 92*10].

Comment: Personally, more than seeing it as a case of KnapSack problem with weight one, this is a Subset Sum problem instance.

Comment: Off-topic: You can build `numberRangeList` like this: `Enumerable.Range(62, 93).ToList()`. There's no need to actually write it all down by hand.

Answer (score 5):

The performance issue is not in the LINQ, but in the problem itself. 
This problem is well known in CS Literature and it's called Subset Sum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem . It's a known problem that belongs to the NP-complete class of time-complexity ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete ). You should do some research for a sub-optimal solution if you don't want to explore the (exponential) problem complexity.

Comment: He doesnt need to look in sub-optimal solutions in his case - maximal sum value obtained by his numberRangeList is 92*10, dynamic programming array size is 9200*32 - not a lot of work for pc.

Comment: That is if his scenario stays the same, what would happen if the boundaries were to change?

Comment: Then there wouldn't be other way than heuristics (at least if P!=NP) :)

Comment: Either an heuristic or an approximation algorithm, that's why in the last sentence I stated that IF he doesn't want to explore the exponential problem complexity, he should research for sub-optimal solutions (Either an approximation or an heuristic).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your query computes all possible combinations of 10 numbers taken from a common number pool. (Or, in database terminology, you're computing a very large cross product.) That is a lot of possibly combinations to process. It's perhaps no surprise it takes 30 seconds just to find the first match.

If I am not thoroughly mistaken, your computation resembles the so-called [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If so, perhaps you can find an optimisation through study of that well-known problem.

**Update:** As per @Saverio Terracciano's comment, treating your issue as an instance of the Knapsack problem might introduce more complexity than strictly required. Perhaps take a look at the [sub-set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to linq, so assumed that if I add ".take(1)", that this would speed things up

Comment: Well, it does. But it all depends on the result you're interested in. `.Take(1)` means that you will only get one result out of several possible number combinations that add up to 772.

Comment: Take is not necessary because you havê first

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I'll have to try something else, I'll look at the "knapsack" computation first.

Comment: Actually, this problem is not a Knapsack problem, but a Subset Sum problem instance.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know about the sub-set sum problem. But what about [Wikipedia stating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) that, _"Subset sum can also be thought of as a special case of the knapsack problem"_?

Comment: You can see the Subset Sum problem as a special case of Knapsack's because you have all the elements with weight 1 and you don't care about the total weight available. While asymptotically the two problems have a comparable complexity, it's easier to tackle such a problem in an easier and most understandable way (without having to deal with an added dimension).

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano: OK, that makes sense. But it's wrong to say that we are *not* dealing with knapsack here; it's just *not neccessary* to treat it as one, because of the unnecessary complexity it introduces over sub-set sum.

Comment: @stakx I agree with you, I worded that the wrong way :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in LINQ query - the problem is that your algorithm complexity is O(n^10) - there is approximately (92-62+1)^10 operations done - that's a lot of work even for modern cpu. You can solve your problem using Knapsack dynamic programming algorithm and then using BFS (breadth-first search) for finding result which contains ten numbers.

Comment: Subset sum is special case of Knapsack. Just item value and weight is equal to number.